# Forgot to put the GCM api key while publishing the app

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, api-key

Forgot to insert the api key while publishing the app on google play. Will it accept the api key if i insert it now. Now that i have got the api key from my server guy so will i have to publish the app again, or put the api key save and republish ? thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you sign the app with the same keystore, increment your version code in your AndroidManifest.xml, and update the version name, you just republish the app and it will be available as an upgrade for existing users in a couple of hours and available for download for new users.

Comment: ok so now all that i need to do is take the api key and put in the api services window where it is asked for and republish the app rite. I hope i dont have to upload the apk again as i am not making any change in the apk.